# can't resolve hostnames after re-tethering

Tags: usb, 16.10, tethering

When I get to the office in the morning, I attach my 5X to my personal laptop via USB and start the laptop (cold boot).  I tell the phone to tether with the laptop, and everything works great.

At lunch, I disconnect the phone and go get something to eat.  After lunch, I return to my desk and re-connect the phone.  I get a message saying "You are connected to Wired Connection 4", and I seem to have an IP address (based on /sbin/ifconfig).  But whenever I try to connect to a website, I get "Host could not be resolved".

If I kill and restart network manager, it all works. If I reboot the system, it all works.  But I don't want to do those things.

this all worked fine in 16.04, the problem appeared when I upgraded to 16.10